# Why is Google Experiments showing significant conversion differences in my A/A test?

Tags: ab-testing, google-experiments

I have implemented an A/B test using Google Experiments.  However, we did not want the A/B test to start for a period of time and therefore put a date driven condition on showing the B variant.  Out of curiosity I started the experiment anyway before the B variant go live date.  Hence, at the start of the experiment, Google Experiments was choosing a variation for me (A or B, see code below) and regardless of the chosen variation, I would show variant A (since we hadn't hit the go live date yet).  This effectively gives me an A/A test which I expected to be a dead heat.  Google doesn't know that I'm showing the exact same page elements to each variant at this stage.

However, I get the following results (showing page views per session):
[image]

The above image shows the results up to the day that the B variant went live.  While I expected some natural variation in the page views, variation B is so consistently winning, that something seems wrong as it is showing an identical page to variation A at this point.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Here's the code we use:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" 
              src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=MY_EXPERIMENT_ID"><!-- --></script>

      <script>
            function enableVariationB(shouldEnable) {
                var enableExperimentDate = new Date(2015, 6, 10);    
                var today = new Date();

                if (today < enableExperimentDate || shouldEnable) {
                    $('#variation_B').show();
                } else {
                    $('#variation_B').hide();
                }
            }

            //Call to Google Experiments to return 1 or 2 depending on 
            //which variation is to be shown to the user
            var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();

            var pageVariations = [
                      function() {  
                          enableVariationB(true);  
                      }, 
                      function() {
                          enableVariationB(false);    
                      }
            ];

            $(document).ready(
                 pageVariations[chosenVariation]
            );
     </script>
```

Comment: just came across this old question... did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Sadly, no, never did :(

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Before looking into the data, in the experiment setup, the `today < enableExperimentDate` check should be done before calling `cxApi.chooseVariation()`.

Reason: Even if a visitor is assigned to variation B from Google's point-of-view, if s/he failed the experiment date check, what a user would see is variation A even if s/he is supposed to be in variation B.

Now, looking at the data,

1. Not enough traffic: How much traffic does your website/application get?  It could be just coincident if the traffic volume is low, and the result is not conclusive.
2. Unclear success metrics/overall evaluation criteria (OEC): Even though variation B has a higher page view count than variation A, what success metric is your experiment trying to optimize?  Looking at just the view count is not  sufficient.
3. Drawing conclusion too early: If the OEC is, for example, increase page view from 1 to 2, based on the traffic volume your site get per day, and let's say it takes 1 month to get that amount of data to reach a 95% confidence on your experiment, experimenter should not look at the result early and conclude that which treatment won or not -- Because it does not have sufficient traffic yet to give you the 95% confidence.
4. It's still positive for a false positive:  Even if we are confident about the result with 95% confidence, there is still a 5% chance of running into false positive result -- Meaning, if you run 20 tests, statistically speaking, 1 of the test result will be incorrect.  That's why it is not uncommon for experimenters to re-run experiments at a later time just to be sure.

Hope the points above help!

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Our traffic is measured in the low thousands per day.  We were attempting to measure increased engagement.  However, with the volume of traffic we have, I expected more variation in the day to day average page views per session.  I've rerun this experiment with an even simpler implementation taking out everything but the call to chooseVariation().  Identical pages served to what Google believes to be two variants and get the same results as above.  My 'variant' outperforms the original every day until Google chose a 'winner' (my variant).